# Chrome breakpoints stop without firing debugger commands

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging background script in chrome extension mv3

I usually use Chrome devtools and it always worked correctly

but as of recently, breakpoints are fired without showing debugger

You can see in the images below that the **breakpoint is fired**, while displaying variables data but **without any debugger commands**

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

[image]
[image: images]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters the same issue, I just reset Chrome and it worked

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en